# Replace entire lines in a .conf file

Tags: bash, sed, dnsmasq

I have a situation where I want a bash script to replace an entire lines in a dnsmasq.conf

By default, lines are :

```
listen-address=192.168.42.1
dhcp-range=192.168.42.1,192.168.42.253,255.255.255.0,192.168.42.255,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.42.1
```

I implement :

```
new_ip=$1
broadcast=$2
base_ip=`echo $new_ip | cut -d"." -f1-3`

sed -i 's/^listen-address.*/listen-address=$new_ip/' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sed -i 's/^dhcp-range.*/dhcp-range=$base_ip.1,$base_ip.254,255.255.255.0,$broadcast,24h/' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sed -i 's/^dhcp-option.*/dhcp-option=option:router,$new_ip/' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

I am calling the bash as ./test.sh 172.24.239.40 172.24.239.255 and I obtain the following lines :

```
listen-address=$new_ip
dhcp-range=$base_ip.1,$base_ip.254,255.255.255.0,$broadcast,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,$new_ip
```

Is it possible to dissociate the parameter from text in sed command lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/^listen-address.*/listen-address=$new_ip/" \
 -e "s/^dhcp-range.*/dhcp-range=$base_ip.1,$base_ip.254,255.255.255.0,$broadcast,24h/" \
 -e "s/^dhcp-option.*/dhcp-option=option:router,$new_ip/" /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

i.e.

- use of double quotes instead of single quotes to allow variables to expand
- use of multiple substitute command in **single sed** instead of calling `sed` multiple times
- use of `-i.bak` to keep original file safe with `.bak` extension

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes when you have variables in sed:

```
sed -i "s/^listen-address.*/listen-address=$new_ip/" /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sed -i "s/^dhcp-range.*/dhcp-range=$base_ip.1,$base_ip.254,255.255.255.0,$broadcast,24h/" /etc/dnsmasq.conf
sed -i "s/^dhcp-option.*/dhcp-option=option:router,$new_ip/" /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```